# Simplify Many-to-Many Relation with Extra Field

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, referential-integrity

I would like to simplify a Many-to-Many Relation complex, composed by key with 4 fields, one of which is used to establish dependency (*serie*: is order of creation).

I know that should break the table and keep dependencies, but after reading and thinking a long time, I do not know how.

Below system that contains the problem, which is represented in-First Normal Form 1NF-, where *Rel_Apply_Lodge* it is the table showing the problem.

**Apply**:

[Key] id_applies

**Rel_Apply_Lodge**:

[Key] [FK] id_applies

[Key] [FK] id_lodging

[Key] [FK] id_kind_boarding

[Key] [extra field] serie *<- solves duplicate rows issue*

**Lodging**:

[Key] id_lodging

[FK] id_kind_booking

[FK] id_municipality

Comment: What's the situation you're trying to modelize??

Comment: **Target:** To manage request (apply for) of lodging/hosting. **User's history:** A person apply for lodging, and in this very moment a relation (Rel_Apply_Lodge) is created. This relation stored: id_apply, id_lodging and id_kind_boarding.

Comment: **Issue:** For each one request is stored one register. In case a person how need to apply for three days, and by same hosting, is when the system stored the same three rows. It's when the serie/order (field) _keeps dependencies and avoids duplicates_.

Comment: why don't you add `number of days` or `duration` as an  attribute in the `Lodging` table.

Comment: because `number of days` it is independent of the `Lodging` entity. `Lodging` manages the accommodation available to users. In the event that the property `number of days` was added, should be done it in other entity. (Why? Because when you have accommodation to be rented, don't specific `number of days`, this will be choosen by the user)

Answer (score 0):

It easier and trivial than it had ever imagined.

To solve it, separates a `Many-to-Many` relation in two: `One-to-Many`.

The unique conditions to achieve succesfully are:

- Maintain the same fields that had `Many-to-Many` relation.
- And, add in both entities an `ID attribute`. These keeps dependencies and solves duplicates issue.

The model looks like this:

**Apply:**
[Key] id_applies

**Rel_Apply_Day:** <--NEW

[Key] id <--NEW

[FK] id_applies

serie <- we can keep the serie indicator

**Rel_Day_Lodge:** <--NEW

[Key] id <--NEW

[FK] id_lodging

[FK] id_kind_boarding

**Lodging:**

[Key] id_lodging

[FK] id_kind_booking

[FK] id_municipality